# How to join three tables from a database using just one common field amongst them all.(Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

These are three tables

```
1. table `p_transactions` has following fields

(`txn_id`, `txn_uid`, `txn_bid_no`, `txn_date`, `txn_desc`, `txn_amt`, `txn_fee`, `txn_mode`, `txn_status`, `txn_mdate`)

2 . table `p_game_results` has following fields.

(`id`, `game_id`, `game_combo`, `game_combo_hr`, `cdate`, `mdate`)

3. Table `p_game_room_results` has following fields

 (`id`, `game_id`, `room_id`, `txn`, `round`, `result`, `score`, `cdate`, `mdate`)
```

I would like to join them using their txn id as a common field.

here's something I tried. but not sure, I'm sure its wrong .

```
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM " . $prefix . "_user_game_results".$prefix."_game_room_results".$prefix."_transactions WHERE". $prefix . "_user_game_result.uid"='$prefix."_game_room_results.id"'. and .$prefix."_transactions.txn_uid"='$prefix."_game_room_results.uid"'"";
        $result = $this->sql_fetchrowset($this->sql_query($sql));
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's this `prefix` all about?

Comment: In the database I have created tables which has prefix as 'p' , 'f' , 'm' "p"- stands for portal i.e for the website game , "f" - stands for facebook and "m"-stands for mobile platform games. We have a game website that accesses tables with prefix as "p" also we are going to launch facebook and mobile game versions of our game, so over there we'll be making use of tables with "f" and "m" as prefix. So just to differentiate between tables we have created those prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    select * 
    from p_transactions as p_t INNER JOIN p_game_results as p_g_r
    ON p_t.txn_id = p_g_r.id
    INNER JOIN
    p_game_room_results as p_g_r_r
    ON p_g_r_r.game_id = p_g_r.game_id;
```

The following alias are used in INNER JOIN

```
   p_transactions as p_t
   p_game_results as p_g_r
   p_game_room_results as p_g_r_r
```

I suggest you to go through these useful SQL Joins Tutorial

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
select * from p_transactions pt 
inner join p_game_room_results pgrr on pgrr.txn=pt.txn_id 
inner join p_game_results pgr on pgr.game_id=pgrr.game_id
```

Joined all tables by their common fields. `p_game_room_results` and `p_game_results` were joined by game id since that seems to be the common field.

Comment: what is  "pgr" and "pgrr" that you have used in the above query, can you explain..Thanks.

Comment: `pgr` and `pgrr` are aliases for `p_game_results` and `p_game_room_results` respectively

Comment: `pt` is the alias for p_transactions